# formula to populate the value in view

Tags: lotus-notes

Please help. I have a querysave event in form. the below is the code snippet. It is for calculating a ref number(settlement number) whose format is "ST115-00001"
Sub Querysave(Source As Notesuidocument, Continue As Variant)

```
Dim w As New notesuiworkspace
Dim uidoc As notesuidocument
Dim SESS    As New NotesSession
Dim RefView As NotesView
Dim DB As NotesDatabase
Dim RefDoc  As NotesDocument
Set DB   =  SESS.CurrentDatabase

Set RefView = DB.GetView("System\AutoNo")
Set uidoc=w.CurrentDocument

Dim approvedcnt As Integer
approvedcnt = Cint(source.fieldgettext("appcnt"))

If uidoc.EditMode = True Then

    Financial_Year =  Clng(Right$(Cstr(Year(Now)),3)) + 104
    If Month(Now) >= 4 Then Financial_Year = Financial_Year + 1
    DocKey     =  Cstr(Financial_Year)& "-"
    New_No      =  0
    Set RefDoc  =  RefView.GetDocumentByKey(DocKey , True)
    If Not(RefDoc Is Nothing) Then New_No = Clng(Right$(RefDoc,5))
    New_No      =  New_No + 1
    autono      =  DocKey & "-" & Right$("00000" & Cstr(New_No) ,5)
    Application ="ST"
    Latest_No = Application + autono
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("SETTLEMENT_NO",Latest_No)
    Call uidoc.Refresh
    Else
    Exit Sub
End If

get_ex_rate
get_cv_local


Call uidoc.FieldSetText("Flag1", "A")

If approvedcnt = 12 And uidoc.FieldGetText("STATUS") = "APPROVE" Then
    Call uidoc.fieldsettext("Flag2", "B")
End If

Dim answer2 As Integer

answer2% = Msgbox("Do you want to save this document?", 1, "Save")
If answer2 = 1 Then 
    Print "Saving"
End If  
If answer2 = 2 Then
    continue=False
    Exit Sub
End If

uidoc.Refresh
uidoc.close
```

End Sub

I need the value of DocKey and New_No to be populated to a view. what formula should i use and is my logic correct. please help.

Regards,
Priya.

Comment: Looks like you just need to add the settlement_no item as a column in your view?  Or if you want the dockey and new_no in your view, just save them to the document like you did for the settlement number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't need to get the view, or do anything to populate it.  Views populate themselves, by means of a selection formula that determines which documents are displayed, and column formulas that determine what values are displayed for each document.  These formulas are edited by opening the specific view in Domino Designer.

If you already have a view that selects the right documents, and that view already has a column for Settlement_No, then you should already be seeing the values like "ST115-00001" in the view.  If you have the view already but it is not showing the Settlement_No data, and if that's the format you want to see the data in the view, then all you need to do is add a column to the view, select "Field", and select "Settlement_No".

If what you're really asking is how to see DocKey and New_No in the view without them being combined, so instead of seeing "ST115-00001" you see "ST115" and "00001", then you have two choices.

1. Modify your code to also save DockKey and New_No in the document, and then add two new columns to the view.  If you don't want to add new visible fields to your form, you will want to use the NotesDocument class and ReplaceItemValue in order to save the DocKey and New_No.
2. Simply to add two view columns, and use @Left(Settlement_No;"-") in the first column formula and @Right(Settlement_No;"-") in the second column formula.

Obviously method 2 is simpler, but method 1 has the advantage that you won't ever have to change it, even if someday you decide to change the formatting of the Settlement_No field so that it looks like this "ST115:00001/more stuff here".

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am able to do it now. For now I have used the 2nd method. the first method will help me in future.Thanks. 
Another problem in the logic now. The document which i add is not getting incremented when i save. it is showing 00001 each time..I m trying to find wat is wrong...can you help.

Comment: I get a type mismatch error now for the same script when i try to save the second document :(

Comment: you should open a new question.